# Handling mouseout css effect

Tags: css, effect, mouseout

```
.box {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fe0000;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 138.88889px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 138.88889px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 138.88889px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 138.88889px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 138.88889px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 138.88889px;
}
.box .shine {
  position: absolute;
  top: -200%;
  left: -200%;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  opacity: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 90%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 90%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)), color-stop(75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)), color-stop(90%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)), color-stop(100%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)));
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 90%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 90%, 6 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 90%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  transition-property: left, top, opacity;
  transition-duration: 0.5s, 0.5s, 0.1s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
.box:hover .shine {
  opacity: 1;
  top: -50%;
  left: -50%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/iaezzy/0ad7pthm/

The shine effect looks good, but if you mouseout from the element, there's a weird glitch. How do I control the mouseout behaviour?

Comment: the fiddle you gave it is working Fine in Firefox v32.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't control `mouseout` property via CSS, but you can remove that glitch by removing `opacity` from `transition-property`:

```
transition-property: left, top;
```

```css
body {
  background: #444;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fe0000;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 138.88889px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 138.88889px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 138.88889px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 138.88889px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 138.88889px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 138.88889px;
}
.box .shine {
  position: absolute;
  top: -200%;
  left: -200%;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  opacity: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 90%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 90%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)), color-stop(75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)), color-stop(90%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)), color-stop(100%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)));
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 90%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 90%, 6 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 90%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  transition-property: left, top;
  transition-duration: 0.5s, 0.5s, 0.1s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
.box:hover .shine {
  opacity: 1;
  top: -50%;
  left: -50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="shine"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah cool, another annoying thing is that until you're hovering over the element, it adds opacity making the red less bright. I just want the shine to pass through it and go away.

Comment: I;m not sure if you can, they are gradients and this how it works